# How to avoid/speed up manually building pandoc on Travis CI?

Tags: ubuntu, travis-ci, pandoc

A project, which builds I wanted to automate with Travis, requires pandoc. Unfortunately the version packaged with Ubuntu 12.04 (1.9.1) exhibits a bug (which completely breaks my build's result) which is fixed in later versions (checked with 1.12 and newer). I couldn't find a way to install/backport newer version of it while still using `sudo: false`. Currently I try to build pandoc completely from source - this works perfectly... but the build time increases from ~1 minute to nearly 20, which is really inconvenient.

This is the relevant section of my current `.travis.yml`:

```
sudo: false
addons:
  apt:
    packages:
    - haskell-platform
install:
- cabal update
- cabal install pandoc
before_script:
- export PATH=$PATH:/home/travis/.cabal/bin
script:
- make my_project
```

The simplest approach would be wait for Travis to move to Ubuntu 14, but I don't see any known timeline for that.

Is there any way I could get the newer pandoc's version without slowing the whole build to a crawl?

Comment: Since you're using `sudo: false`, can't you just cache the pandoc version that you built from source? See http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/caching/

Comment: Oh, it actually works on a free account! I apparently wrongly interpreted "`only available for private repositories`" as "only for paid accounts". So what repositories isn't this available for then?

Comment: Caching is not available for free repositories that use `sudo: true`.

Answer (score 1):

You could add "dist: trusty" to your travis yaml to get a newer vm on travis.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to use Pandoc in my Travis CI configuration like this:

```
addons:
  apt_packages:
    - pandoc
```

Works very well.

Answer (score 0):

Using the caching service reduces the build time back to 1-2 minutes, thanks.

Comment: How did you use the caching service with pandoc?

Answer (score 0):

If you can set your Travis config language to R, then you can chose Pandoc version to be installed.

> The R environment comes with LaTeX and pandoc pre-installed, making it easier to use packages like RMarkdown or knitr.

See the [docs](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/r/#Pandoc):

> The default pandoc version installed is 1.15.2. Alternative pandoc releases can be installed by setting the pandoc_version to the desired version.
>
> ```
> language: r
> pandoc_version: 1.16
> ```